# Javascript object.value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies

In one of my javascripts I have an object that contains all cookies currently saved. This object is obtained by:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";").
map(function(el){ return el.split("="); }).
reduce(function(prev,cur){ prev[cur[0]] = cur[1]; return prev },{});
```

Afterwards I am reading the cookie object as follows:

```
console.log(cookies);
var json = cookies['tracks'];
console.log(json);
```

the console output looks like a normal javascript object:

```
Object { PHPSESSID: "e964d0b67bbabd149906473b6b2183d5",  
         tracks: "%7B%22test%22%3A%22tested%22%2C%2223%22%3A%22ert%22%7D" }
undefined
```

however, the variable JSON remains undefined independent of whether i use `cookies.tracks` or `cookies["tracks"]` or of which browser I use or whether I try to check the `PHPSESSID` cookie or the `tracks` cookie. Any idea why this could be the case?

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked before, however, none of the answers given applied to this case.

Comment: The code you have provided seems perfectly fine. What happens if you try to log the `json` variable immediately after assignment? Where do you use this variable and find it undefined?

Comment: Are you sure the two parts are in the same scope? I can't see how that could happen otherwise.

Comment: I edited the question, i get the undefined right from the second console.log(json) call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running into an issue of extra spaces in your keys, as a result of the `split()`.

When you split on ";", your key values will have a prepended space in front of them, which will get carried on throughought the rest of your processing.  If you view the DOM version of your "cookies" object in Firebug, right click on, `tracks`, click "Copy Path", and paste the result, I'm willing to bet that you will see this:  `[" tracks"]`.

To resolve, you can either trim the spaces somewhere in your logic, or reference the property using `cookies[" tracks"]`.

Comment: Yes, there indeed is a space in front of the key 'tracks'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good catch. I thought about this as well, but Chrome formats keys differently if they contain leading or trailing spaces: `Object {" tracks": 42}`. It's always a good idea to specify the browser you are using, @Erik.

Comment: @FelixKling - I actually sort of wondered about that . . . how the different browsers format `cookie` strings . . .